Find if this series is convergent or divergent
So I have been given this question by our professor as an extra question and I have solved it to some extent but I've been stuck, I'll write my approach in here and I would like some help. So this is the series I have been given:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1\times3\times ...\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times...\times2n}\right)^P$$
I used the ratio test to prove that this series is either divergent or convergent:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(\frac{\frac{1\times3\times...(2n-1)\times(2n+1)}{2\times4\times...\times(2n)\times(2n+2)}}{\frac{1\times3\times...\times(2n-1)}{2\times4\times...\times2n}}\right)^P$$
Which is equal to:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)^P$$
Now if we take the limit of this we would have:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)^P = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{2+\frac{1}{n}}{2+\frac{2}{n}}\right)^P = \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^P = 1^P $$
Which for every P we get 1.
So the ratio test fails to determine either this series is convergent of divergent. I have done some researching and there is a test called Sterling's approximation but we haven't studied that yet and I have to comment that this question came up in my real analysis course so if there is another "analytic" way to solve this I would appreciate the help.

You might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71501/using-little-o-notation-to-prove-series-convergence?noredirect=1.

Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1511481
